# Consulta con STUFF devuelve todos los valores consultados en lugar del solicitado

Tags: sql-server

Quiero sacar en una sola línea los datos de clientes y los de otra tabla de teléfonos y emails para asociar los que tienen ciertas características concretas, al asociar esos clientes a sus formas de contacto no consigo que solo me devuelva solamente las suyas, sino que me devuelve todas las formas de contacto de todos lo clientes por cada cliente.

Mi intención ha sido usando STUFF sacar los datos de la tabla de formas de contacto junto al resto de datos consultados por cliente, asociados por la id del cliente pero me da todos los datos repetidos cuando solamente necesito los 2 o 3 asociados a esa id. Haciendo las consultas por separado me da los valores correctos pero nunca había usado STUFF y quizá haya perdido algo por el camino.

```
SELECT COUNT
(POLIZAS.POL_Estado) AS POLIZAS_ACTIVAS,
POLIZAS.CLI_Id,
CLIENTES.CLI_NIF,
CLIENTES.CLI_Apellido1,
CLIENTES.CLI_Apellido2,
CLIENTES.CLI_Nombre,
STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + DIRECCIONES.DIR_TelfPal,
            ', ' + DIRECCIONES.DIR_TelfSec,
            ', ' + DIRECCIONES.DIR_TelfMovil,
            ', ' + DIRECCIONES.DIR_Email
FROM DIRECCIONES
INNER JOIN CLIENTES ON DIRECCIONES.CLI_Id = CLIENTES.CLI_ID
GROUP BY 
    DIRECCIONES.DIR_TelfPal,
    DIRECCIONES.DIR_TelfSec,
    DIRECCIONES.DIR_TelfMovil,
    DIRECCIONES.DIR_Email
FOR XML PATH ('')
), 1, 0, '') as 'Contacto'  FROM
POLIZAS JOIN CLIENTES ON POLIZAS.CLI_Id = CLIENTES.CLI_Id WHERE 
POLIZAS.POL_ESTADO = 2 GROUP BY
    POLIZAS.CLI_ID,
    CLIENTES.CLI_NIF,
    CLIENTES.CLI_Apellido1,
    CLIENTES.CLI_Apellido2,
    CLIENTES.CLI_Nombre HAVING
COUNT(POLIZAS.POL_Estado) < 3 ORDER BY
CLIENTES.CLI_NIF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empecemos por aclarar algo. `STUFF` no concatena nada, la concatenación es generada por la instrucción `FOR XML`. `STUFF` lo que hace es quitar la primer coma.

Dicho eso, el problema es que la subconsulta que tienes, no está relacionada con la consulta general. Para eso hay que usar la clausula WHERE. Me di la libertad de darle un formato distinto a tu consulta y agregar alias a las tablas.

```
SELECT  COUNT(P.POL_Estado) AS POLIZAS_ACTIVAS,
        P.CLI_Id,
        C.CLI_NIF,
        C.CLI_Apellido1,
        C.CLI_Apellido2,
        C.CLI_Nombre,
        STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + D.DIR_TelfPal,
                       ', ' + D.DIR_TelfSec,
                       ', ' + D.DIR_TelfMovil,
                       ', ' + D.DIR_Email
                FROM DIRECCIONES AS D
                WHERE D.CLI_Id = P.CLI_Id 
                GROUP BY 
                        D.DIR_TelfPal,
                        D.DIR_TelfSec,
                        D.DIR_TelfMovil,
                        D.DIR_Email
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '') as 'Contacto'  
FROM POLIZAS AS P
JOIN CLIENTES AS C ON P.CLI_Id = C.CLI_Id 
WHERE P.POL_ESTADO = 2 
GROUP BY
    P.CLI_ID,
    C.CLI_NIF,
    C.CLI_Apellido1,
    C.CLI_Apellido2,
    C.CLI_Nombre 
HAVING COUNT(P.POL_Estado) < 3 
ORDER BY C.CLI_NIF;
```

Comment: Hola, Luis, gracias por la respuesta. Al introducir el código  me da este error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
La columna 'CLIENTES.CLI_Id' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: Perdón, fue porque estaba usando la columna de la tabla de clientes y en el resto de la consulta estás usando la de polizas. Cambié la condición para utilizar también la columna de la tabla Polizas.

Comment: Ahora va a la perfección, muchísimas gracias.